# AutoMapper 6.0 Revised Mapping to handle TimeZone conversion

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, timezone, automapper

I've two functions:
**1st:**

```
private DateTime LocalTime(DateTime? value)
{
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("TimeZone String ID");
DateTime dtz = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc((DateTime)value, tz);
return dtz;
}
```

**2nd:**

```
private DateTime UTCTime(DateTime? value)
{
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("TimeZone StringID");
DateTime dtz = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc((DateTime)value, tz);
return dtz;
}
```

I'm mapping to change DateTime? from user input to UTC like this

```
CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing(dt => LocalTime(dt));
```

This mapping is working perfectly, the problem is this mapping is done on (Entity,ViewModel)

I need to do similar mapping for (ViewModel,Entity) but this time I need to covert from LocalTime to UTCTime, in other word
When I have (Entity,Model) then convert UTC to Local
and
When I have (Model,Entity) then convert Local to UTC.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Automapper is really the wrong place to be doing this.  Time zone conversion should be treated as business logic and addressed with each use case.  Trying to hide it via mappings is going to get you into trouble eventually.

Comment: `CreateMap<Test, TestModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.RegistrationDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Portal.LocalTime(src.RegistrationDate)));
CreateMap<TestModel, Test>().ForMember(dest => dest.RegistrationDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Portal.UTCTime(src.RegistrationDate)));`